# Phoenix Framework - Index should show message where state == "new"

Tags: elixir

I'm looking to show only messages with a state of "new" in the def index.

Here is the working code I have to show all messages:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  messages = Repo.all(Message)
  render(conn, "index.json", messages: messages)
end
```

I'm trying to filter the messages to only show ones that have a state of "new". Here is the code I tried unsuccessfully:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  messages = Repo.all(Message
  |> where([message], message.state == "sent"))
  render(conn, "index.json", messages: messages)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Ecto.Query` for your querying needs:

```
import Ecto.Query
query = from m in Message, where: m.state == "sent", select: m
Repo.all(query)
```

Take a look at the docs: [Ecto.Query](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html)

Comment: Thank you!  Is there also a way to check for messages where "m.user_id == conn.assigns.authenticated_user.id" in addition to the state?

Comment: Sure, you can have multiple `where` clauses in your query - `from m in Message, where: m.state == "sent", where: (...), select: m`